# Node JS or Play For Web App and Possibly Mobile

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, web-applications, playframework

So i am planning on making my own web app/ mobile app and i am not sure where to start with choosing the technologies to use. Essentially the app will display a list of items sorted by distance from you or price. This allows people to see which stores near them sell which items and at which price, along with where the cheapest particular item is. So they can see store A and B bother sell item 1 but store A sells it for cheaper.

So for the front end obviously HTML, CSS and Javascript. In the backend is where i would like some help. Should i use a framework to make the api? If so should i use play? or node? or another one. I have been doing a lot of reading about node being good for I/O apps since its async and you can make a REST API quickly passing JSON which from my understanding is all i will be doing. Thoughts? Am i over thinking this?

Comment: I think you are. Choose the one that makes more sense to you. NodeJS is more lightweight than Play (although IMO Play is very lightweight compared to others Java frameworks) and has better support to JSON, but IMO maintaining Java/Scala code is easier than JS code and programming asynchronously may also be more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

nodejs sails module is great and will make things easy to you:
http://sailsjs.org/